# google youtube api on Django

Tags: django

I'm working on a website to get videos via key words using google api on Django. The function for calling api works well individually, but once I called the function in view.py and run the server, it returns server error. why?

```
def youtube_search(options):


  DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIzaSyBQG9ozouzPofCHE4J-BHdUeSjqqtemnc0"
  YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
  YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("--q", help="Search term", default=options)
  parser.add_argument("--max-results", help="Max results", default=1) # 
the number of default is the number of output videos
  options= parser.parse_args()


  search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=options.q,
    part="id,snippet",
    maxResults=options.max_results
  ).execute()

  videos = []
  videoid = []
  channels = []
  playlists = []
  result = []


  for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
    if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
      videos.append(  search_result["snippet"]["title"])
      videoid.append(  search_result["id"]["videoId"])

  for line in videos:

    result.append(line)

  for line1 in videoid:
    line1 = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+line1
    result.append(line1)

  return result
```

and here are the view.py calling the function:

```
def index2(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    search=request.POST.get("search:",None)
    class1 = predict.predict(search)
    #list =[search, 'other corresponding tags']

    api = YTapi.youtube_search(search)
    video = api[0]
    videoid = api[1]
return render(request, "index2.html",{"video":video,"videoid":videoid})
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO. You might wanna update the question with the error message you are getting. Might have set the `DEBUG = True` on django's `settings.py` to get a detail error message.